# Create PASCAL Voc for Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, object-detection

This question is an extension of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44810459/4962554).

**TLDR;**
I'm trying to train the TS Object Detection API using my own dataset. For proof of concept, I decided to adhere my dataset to the Pascal VOC 2012 benchmark.

At the moment, I am trying to create a TFRecord from my Pascal VOC annotations.

Looking at [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/create_pascal_tf_record.py#L162) in their *create_pascal_tf_record.py* script, they're just grabbing the aeroplane's *descriptor*; lack of a better word, text file. Why is this so? What about the other classes' descriptors?

**Side Note**

This file; titled *aeroplane_train.txt*, was included along with the [Pascal VOC 2012 dataset](http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/voc2012/VOCtrainval_11-May-2012.tar) inside VOC2012/ImageSets/Main/.

A peek into the file shows that the first column represents an image name and the -1 or 1 states whether that particular image consists of the class(aeroplane) we're interested in.

Partial contents of the *aeroplane_train.txt* file:

```
2008_000008 -1
2008_000015 -1
2008_000019 -1
2008_000023 -1
2008_000028 -1
2008_000033  1
2008_000036 -1
2008_000037  1
2008_000041 -1
2008_000045 -1
2008_000053 -1
2008_000060 -1
2008_000066 -1
2008_000070 -1
2008_000074 -1
2008_000085 -1
2008_000089 -1
2008_000093 -1
2008_000095 -1
2008_000096 -1
2008_000097 -1
2008_000099 -1
2008_000103 -1
2008_000105 -1
2008_000109 -1
2008_000112 -1
2008_000128 -1
2008_000131 -1
2008_000132 -1
2008_000141 -1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44810459/tensorflow-object-detection-api).  The punchline is that we currently only look at the first column of the aeroplane_train.txt file (which is the same as the other xxx_train.txt files) and lets us figure out the path for each image in the training set.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I decided to share [my experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973184/train-tensorflow-object-detection-on-own-dataset/44973203#44973203) after successfully getting it to work. Would be awesome to have your two cents on how I'd've made better for future reference.

Comment: May i ask, the significance of adding a boolean value after the image, why bother because we have the images listed in trainval.txt and test.txt. why even seperate out each class. Do the images followed by -1, taken as negative images for that class which I think will further help for lower FPs. ?

Comment: why is this file named aeroplane? I don't have aeroplanes in my dataset.