# Train Tensorflow Object Detection on own dataset

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, object-detection

After spending a couple days trying to achieve this task, I would like to share my experience of how I went about answering the question:

*How do I use [TS Object Detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) to train using my own dataset?*

Comment: you're a boss, thanks!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This assumes the module is already installed. Please refer to their [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md) if not.

**Disclaimer**

This answer is not meant to be the *right* or *only* way of training the object detection module. This is simply I sharing my experience and what has worked for me. I'm open to suggestions and learning more about this as I am still new to ML in general.

**TL;DR**

1. Create your own PASCAL VOC format dataset
2. Generate TFRecords from it
3. Configure a pipeline
4. Visualize

Each section of this answer consists of a corresponding Edit (see below). After reading each section, please read its Edit as well for clarifications. Corrections and tips were added for each section.

**Tools used**

[LabelImg](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg): A tool for creating PASCAL VOC format annotations.

**1. Create your own PASCAL VOC dataset**

**PS:** *For simplicity, the folder naming convention of my answer follows that of Pascal VOC 2012*

A peek into the [May 2012 dataset](http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/voc2012/VOCtrainval_11-May-2012.tar), you'll notice the folder as having the following structure

`+VOCdevkit
  +VOC2012
    +Annotations
    +ImageSets
      +Action
      +Layout
      +Main
      +Segmentation
    +JPEGImages
    +SegmentationClass
    +SegmentationObject`

For the time being, amendments were made to the following folders:

***Annotations***: This is were all the images' corresponding XML files will be placed in. Use the suggested tool above to create the annotations. Do not worry about `<truncated>` and `<difficulty>` tags as they will be ignored by the training and eval binaries.

***JPEGImages***: Location of your actual images. Make sure they are of type JPEG because that's what is currently supported in order to create TFRecords using their provided script.

***ImageSets->Main***: This simply consists of text files. For each class, there exists a corresponding *train.txt*, *trainval.txt* and *val.txt*. Below is a sample of the contents of the *aeroplane_train.txt* in the VOC 2012 folder

```
2008_000008 -1
2008_000015 -1
2008_000019 -1
2008_000023 -1
2008_000028 -1
2008_000033  1
```

The structure is basically image name followed by a boolean saying whether the corresponding object exists in that image or not. Take for example image *2008_000008* does not consist of an aeroplane hence marked with a *-1* but image *2008_000033* does.

I wrote a small Python script to generate these text files. Simply iterate through the image names and assign a 1 or -1 next to them for object existence. I added some randomness among my text files by shuffling the image names.

The *{classname}_val.txt* files consist of the <strike>testing</strike> validation datasets. Think of this as the test data during training. You want to divide your dataset into training and validation. More info can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set). The format of these files is similar to that of training.

At this point, your folder structure should be

`+VOCdevkit
  +VOC2012
    +Annotations
     --(for each image, generated annotation)
    +ImageSets
      +Main
        --(for each class, generated *classname*_train.txt and *classname*_val.txt)
    +JPEGImages
     --(a bunch of JPEG images)`

---

**1.1 Generating label map**

With the dataset prepared, we need to create the corresponding label maps.
Navigate to *models/object_detection/data* and open *pascal_label_map.pbtxt*.

This file consists of a JSON that assigns an ID and name to each item. Make amendments to this file to reflect your desired objects.

---

**2. Generate TFRecords**

If you look into their code especially this [line](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/create_pascal_tf_record.py#L162), they explicitly grab the *aeroplane_train.txt* only. For curios minds, [here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891732/create-pascal-voc-for-tensorflow-object-detection-api/44937455#44937455). Change this file name to any of your class train text file.

Make sure *VOCdevkit* is inside *models/object_detection* then you can go ahead and [generate the TFRecords](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/preparing_inputs.md#generating-the-pascal-voc-tfrecord-files).

Please go through their code first should you run into any problems. It is self explanatory and well documented.

---

**3. Pipeline Configuration**

The [instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/configuring_jobs.md) should be self explanatory to cover this segment. Sample configs can be found in [*object_detection/samples/configs*](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs).

For those looking to train from scratch as I did, just make sure to remove the `fine_tune_checkpoint` and `from_detection_checkpoint` nodes. [Here's](https://pastebin.com/z7a2G2Dq) what my config file looked like for reference.

From here on you can continue with the [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md#running-the-training-job) and run the training process.

---

**4. Visualize**

Be sure to run the eval in parallel to the training in order to be able to visualize the learning process. To quote [Jonathan Huang](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1877)

> the best way is to just run the eval.py binary. We typically run this
>   binary in parallel to training, pointing it at the directory holding
>   the checkpoint that is being trained. The eval.py binary will write
>   logs to an `eval_dir` that you specify which you can then point to
>   with Tensorboard.
>
> You want to see that the mAP has "lifted off" in the first few hours,
>   and then you want to see when it converges. It's hard to tell without
>   looking at these plots how many steps you need.

---

**EDIT I (28 July '17):**

I never expected my response to get this much attention so I decided to come back and review it.

**Tools**

For my fellow Apple users, you could actually use [RectLabel](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rectlabel-labeling-images-for-object-detection/id1210181730?mt=12) for annotations.

**Pascal VOC**

After digging around, I finally realized that *trainval.txt* is actually the union of training and validation datasets.

Please look at their [official development kit](https://pjreddie.com/media/files/VOC2012_doc.pdf) to understand the format even better.

**Label Map Generation**

At the time of my writing, ID 0 represents `none_of_the_above`. It is recommended that your IDs start from 1.

**Visualize**

After running your evaluation and directed tensorboard to your Eval directory, it'll show you the mAP of each category along with each category's performance. This is good but I like seeing my training data as well in parallel with Eval.

To do this, run tensorboard on a different port and point it to your train directory

```
tensorboard --logdir=${PATH_TO_TRAIN} --port=${DESIRED_NUMBER}
```

Comment: it's great to hear that someone got the TF "training locally" example up and running and also modified it for their own dataset! could you let me know what version of Python you used? I am constantly running into Python2.7/Python3 code issues when just trying to run their example for training on PASCAL. thanks!

Comment: I used Python 2.7 and I believe their codebase was written with that in mind.

Comment: thanks. I ended up shifting to 2.7 as well and things were better.

Comment: How do you run eval.py simultaneously with train.py ? I have to do it on another device, for memory reasons, but I don't know how to specify the device...

Comment: And do you know how to get the same summaries in tensorboard for the evaluation as for the training ? (TotalLoss, global_step/sec, etc., to compare eval and train more precisely, and get the inference time)

Comment: @gdelab I have no idea on how to run _eval.py_ from another device. I ran mine locally by simply opening up a new terminal window. One way I can think of is by you uploading your results into a server, then pull them down on another device and run them there.. To answer your second question, even I've been trying to get that working but no success. I'll update [your Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1927) should I find a way

Comment: @eshirima , so we need to first create an image classification model? perhaps using inception?

Comment: @rambossa. No no no no.. Classification is different from object localization. Classification simply tells you if a certain object exists in your image without actually telling you where in the image. Object localization extends this to include the location of the detected object. If what you want is classification, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44685875/tensorflow-and-opencv-real-time-classification) will help you. But if what you want is object detection, just follow the instructions of this answer.

Comment: @eshirima perfect thanks, Detection is definitely what I want, just wasn't sure if classification was a requirement. Thanks for the good and helpful work

Comment: @rambossa Anytime.. Don't forget to upvote the answer if it helps resolve your issue.. Happy coding. Cheers mate!!

Comment: @eshirima , how did you go about deciding on the size of the images in the training set? I currently have a set of large images, 2880X1800, but am worried these are too big. I would want the images to be as close to real-world resolutions as possible and am afraid that reducing the image size might hurt accuracy when detecting the actual objects. Thoughts?

Comment: 2880X1800 is too big for sure. If you look at the config file under `image_resizer`, the object detector ends up resizing every image to 300X300. I feed it images of 618X816 though and it still does a good job of detecting my desired classes. I'd recommend resizing the images first before running the detection to see what scales still maintain a good visual of your objects (this is what I did as well). You could also tweak around the parameters for `image_resizer`, run your detector and compare results.

Comment: @eshirima thanks, So the resizer is also smart enough to adjust the annotations and bounding drawn for the original images?

Comment: I can't give u a concrete answer to that but in the core, the bounding boxes are *estimates* of the location of the pixels that consist of a majority of your objects' attributes/features. The final box that you see is actually a result of multiple closely-packed boxes grouped together. The issue with feeding the entire 2880X1800 is that you'd end up having too many features that'd be impossible to hold them in memory and computationally penalizing resulting to a single layer computation taking a long time.

Comment: The idea behind resizing is to find enough features such that they can be held in memory but not as penalizing computationally.. Theoretically, once it has learnt all of these features, it should be able to find them as well in larger images. But processing large frames is still an ongoing problem in computer vision.

Comment: @eshirima I tried to train the model with just 5 images of examples . I converted my data set to Tfrecords with oxfard IIT format. (Using the pet script)

But my model giving errors when executing . IIT gives warning of having sparse metrics so I thought of changing the batch size in the config file. But by default it is 1 . So what should I change ?

Comment: @ShamaneSiriwardhana Was it giving u errors or warnings? If errors, what were they? The batch size is just the number of images you want to feed in at a time. I'm not sure if that'll help resolve the warnings/errors. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41176694/4962554) will help u understand batch sizes

Comment: @eshirima I know what is batch size. In the default config it says one . Normally in the sgd we take a mini batch . So why they have put 1 batch size in the config file? 

Yes they are warning (!!) .  This is the error 

"The replica master 0 ran out-of-memory and exited with a non-zero status of 247"

Comment: @ShamaneSiriwardhana [Which](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection/samples/configs) config file are you using? All of them, with exception to ssd extractors have `batch_size:1`. It does make sense why they'd do so because they don't know the users' available memory so set it to the lowest batch size. Also how big are your images? How much memory do u have? I did my training on a 16GB machine. Try tweaking the image size parameters in the config file as well. Or it may be that the model is just too big to keep in memory. Train on _mobilenet_ instead then.

Comment: I am using the cloud . The config file was the one in the pet detection tutorial . I actually trained the pet detector as given in the tutorial. Then I wanted to train it for detect two objects , I took only 5 examples and then converted in to tfrecords and uploaded it to the cloud as it given in the tutorial. But I got errors saying "sparsity matrices can take lot of memory etc" . I think it's lake of data to train on the cloud , What do you think

Comment: @ShamaneSiriwardhana I trained mine locally. Its funny you should say the memory thing because I received a warning as well
> Userwarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape.This may consume a large amount of memory. "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "

But it never actually stopped or crashed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150331/discussion-between-eshirima-and-shamane-siriwardhana).

Comment: @eshirima I think I found the error. It's my image size(nearly 3Mb) and the height and width . In  what scale I should keep these things ?

Comment: @ShamaneSiriwardhana You mentioned that your training images are of 2880 by 1800. How big is the object you are trying to detect in each image? Did your training success eventually? I am building an object detector on my own data, all images are of 1920 b 1080. Each object needed to be detected is only about 50 by 15. It is difficult for me to obtain decent results.

Comment: If the TS Object Detection  can be combined with transfer learning ?

Comment: How do I apply model to test images? How can I get rectangles? This is whats missing.

Answer (score 16):

I wrote a [blog post](https://medium.com/@datitran/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9) on Medium about my experience as well on how I trained an object detector (in particular, it's a Raccoon detector) with Tensorflow on my own dataset. This might also be useful for others and is complimentary to eshirima's answer.

Comment: I actually looked @ your real-time post as well and learnt a lot from it. A couple questions/suggestions. 1: In the config file, do you have an idea of what `num_hard_examples` and `num_examples` represents? 2: For image annotations on a Mac, you could've used [RectLabel](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rectlabel-labeling-images-for-object-detection/id1210181730?mt=12). 3: I was actually about to explore training on own dataset which isn't of Pascal Voc format. You beat me to the punch :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestions:) I had a look at RectLabel. Looks pretty good. I will give it a try. Concerning your first question, `num_hard_examples` has something to do with the hard example miner. Have a look at this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.03540) to understand this. The `num_examples` has something to do with the evaluation. During the evaluation it fetches images and you need to specify how much you have. They also used `max_eval` to limit evaluation process. For number 3:) Yeh doesn't matter haha it's not who comes first but learning from each other.

Comment: Hi did you add hard negative samples when training the ssd. Because the paper says it will work better if we add hard negative samples .

Comment: I read your blog @DatTran and i have one question! can we train our dataset using CPU?

Comment: @Yirga sure but that can take a while.

Comment: @DatTran if we wanted to train for rectangular detection,  and trained images on such rectangles, do you think your method would be better at creating a model that recognizes those specific/actual rectangular boundings (vs jumpy bounds like the racoon)?

Comment: @rambossa if you care about the stability of those rectangular, you should have a look at [ROLO](https://github.com/Guanghan/ROLO).

Comment: @DatTran 


Hi I am trying to train SSD -mobilenet in-order to detect 13 classes. I also trained a faster rcnn -resnet101 .

My training data images have resolution of 265 * 450 . (most of them) and each class had 400 images.

Then this weird thing happened faster rcnn converged faster with batch size of 1 .

But my SSD didn't . It's not converging at all . Here I will put the two graphs ,

Here are the loss graphs 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45633957/ssd-mobilenet-object-detection-algorithm-not-converging

Comment: @eshirima  I found a nice explanation about hard negative samples from the SSD research paper . Normally when we talking the loss most number of default boxes are negative . So there is an imbalance . So we will select at negative boxes with highest confidence loss (Which means top most things algorithm couldn't correctly identify them as background ). 
"we sort them using the highest confidence loss for each
default box and pick the top ones so that the ratio between the negatives and positives is
at most 3:1. We found that this leads to faster optimization and a more stable training"

Comment: @ShamaneSiriwardhana Which paper? Is it titled _SSD: Single Shot MultiBox Detector_

Comment: @eshirima
Yeah . That's the paper. Check with those quotes . And did you get any false positive examples ?

Comment: @eshirima I have this question which data set orientation is good ?  Oxford IIT or PASCAL . I think with oxford IIT when converting data in to TF records you can only have one class in the training image. No multiple types .

Comment: @ShamaneSiriwardhana I encountered some false positive detections after training. This is prone to happen because the model isn't guaranteed to always be 100% correct since the _mAP_ never fully converges to 0. Regarding data sets, I used PASCAL because it was the industry standard before [ImageNet](http://image-net.org/index) hence a larger community.

Comment: @eshirima There is no much difference between pascal and oxford IIT .  In the given converting script for oxford data set uses image name as the label of the data . So which means we can only draw one bounding box in an image. That box should  belongs to class that indicated by image name . But in the given script for converting pascal data set , it's clear that it obtain the class from the object name in XML file. So we can draw multiple objects in one image. Any way my image set had only one bounding box per an image. What about you ? You had many ground truth boxes ?

Comment: @eshirima Refer to code in this from TF-OD API . https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/core/losses.py#L339

Comment: Do you think than can affect the accuracy ?

Comment: @DatTran do you have any insight on more accurate result bounding boxes? (ones that can skew and rotate with the object detected) vs the generic square around the result. I've seen some opencv examples that seem to do this...

Comment: May I know if the TS Object Detection can be combined with transfer learning ?

Comment: @Jason yes. you can load already trained models and refine them on your dataset. Consider asking another question with more details