# Train Tensorflow Obejct Detection without bounding boxes annotations

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, object-detection

I managed to retrain the [object detection module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973184/train-tensorflow-object-detection-on-own-dataset) on my own dataset by adhering it to the PASCAL VOC format shown below.

This format is *bounding box* oriented and peeking into their [TFRecords creation scripts](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/create_pascal_tf_record.py), it does expect a good number of these *groundtruth* values to generate corresponding TFRecords.

The problem with bounding boxes, is that it gives you approximations and annotating rotated images can be rather challenging.

After looking around, I came across [labelme](http://labelme.csail.mit.edu/Release3.0/) which allows you to perform shape (point to point) annotations, as well instead of just bounding box. Below is a short version of the produced annotation along with the resulting image consisting of the resulting shape.

My questions are:

1. Concentrating on the contents of `<polygon></polygon>`, does the [Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection) support point to point annotations?
2. If yes to 1, how do I go about creating the TFRecords for it? What other changes need to be made to accommodate this?

**Pascal VOC Format**

```
<annotation verified="no">
  <folder>VOC2012</folder>
  <filename>pic.jpg</filename>
  <source>
    <database>Unknown</database>
  </source>
  <size>
    <width>214</width>
    <height>300</height>
    <depth>3</depth>
  </size>
  <segmented>0</segmented>
  <object>
    <name>sample</name>
    <pose>Unspecified</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>
      <xmin>32</xmin>
      <ymin>37</ymin>
      <xmax>180</xmax>
      <ymax>268</ymax>
    </bndbox>
  </object>
</annotation>
```

**Snapshot of point-to-point annotation**

[Here's](https://pastebin.com/XerdRe6i) the full annotation file and the corresponding [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AaQ9.jpg)

```
<annotation>
    <filename>ipad.jpg</filename>
    <folder>sample</folder>
    <source>
    <submittedBy>username</submittedBy>
    </source>
    <imagesize>
        <nrows>450</nrows>
        <ncols>800</ncols>
    </imagesize>
    <object>
        <name>ipad</name>
        <deleted>0</deleted><verified>0</verified><occluded>no</occluded>
        <attributes></attributes>
        <parts>
            <hasparts></hasparts>
            <ispartof></ispartof>
        </parts>
        <date>12-Jul-2017 19:20:22</date><id>0</id>
        <polygon>
            <username>anonymous</username>
            <pt><x>40</x><y>76</y></pt>
            <pt><x>435</x><y>11</y></pt>
            <pt><x>472</x><y>311</y></pt>
            <pt><x>94</x><y>418</y></pt>
        </polygon>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>screen</name>
        <deleted>0</deleted>
        <verified>0</verified>
        <occluded>no</occluded>
        <attributes></attributes>
        <parts>
            <hasparts></hasparts>
            <ispartof></ispartof>
        </parts>
        <date>12-Jul-2017 19:20:48</date><id>1</id>
        <polygon>
            <username>anonymous</username>
            <pt><x>75</x><y>89</y></pt>
            <pt><x>118</x><y>397</y></pt>
            <pt><x>447</x><y>308</y></pt>
            <pt><x>421</x><y>30</y></pt>
        </polygon>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tensorflow Object Detection API only performs Bounding Box annoations.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How would you recommend handling rotations then? And uh is point-to-point annotation training even feasible for object localization in ML?

Comment: The current state only allows bounding boxes. When you have polygons or other shapes you must transfer them to boundings boxes before training. Facebook's [Multipathnet](https://github.com/facebookresearch/multipathnet) can be trained on polygons.

Comment: How to convert polygons to bounding box format? Is there any known way to do it? Or maybe writing script to get the extreme corners of the polygon.

Comment: as Derek mentioned, the api use to only perform bounding box annotations, it now supports masks though using MASK RCNN, https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/instance_segmentation.md

Comment: This answer is wrong. You can pass images without bboxes to tf od by passing an empty list to the tfrecord producer