# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError while generating TFRecord files Object Detection API

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to generate **TFRecord files** from **Pascal VOC** format dataset. I am following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973184/train-tensorflow-object-detection-on-own-dataset) and used [this instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/preparing_inputs.md#generating-the-pascal-voc-tfrecord-files) to create *pascal_train.record* *and pascal_val.record*.

I have already prepared annotations, images and image sets in ***ImageSets -> Main***. Also generated label map in *pascal_label_map.pbtxt*.

Now, when run following command from *tf_worspace/models*:

```
python3 object_detection/create_pascal_tf_record.py \
--label_map_path=object_detection/data/pascal_label_map.pbtxt \
--data_dir=VOCdevkit --year=VOC2012 --set=train \
--output_path=pascal_train.record
```

I get:

> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py",
>   line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
>       pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status)) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError:
>   VOCdevkit/VOC2012/ImageSets/Main/marlboro_red_train.txt

My project structure is as follow:

- tf_workspace

  - models *(TF staff here...)*

    - object_detection

      - VOCdevkit

        - VOC2012

          - Annotations
          - ImageSets

            - Action *(my annotations here)*
            - Layout
            - Main *(my imagesets here)*

              - marlboro_red_train.txt
              - marlboro_red_val.txt
              - marlboro_red_trainval.txt
              - ...
            - Segmentation
          - JPEGImages *(my images here)*
          - SegmentationClass
          - SegmentationObject

The file that script cannot find for some reasons exist in that directory, I have checked few times.

Be sure I changed following line in ***create_pascal_tf_record.py***:

```
examples_path = os.path.join(data_dir, year, 'ImageSets', 'Main',
                                 'aeroplane_' + FLAGS.set + '.txt')
```

to:

```
examples_path = os.path.join(data_dir, year, 'ImageSets', 'Main',
                                 'marlboro_red_' + FLAGS.set + '.txt')
```

So what is going on? Can anybody explain why it gives such error, please!
Thanks in advance for any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the reason was because of wrong parameters.
As [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973184/train-tensorflow-object-detection-on-own-dataset) says:

> Make sure VOCdevkit is inside models/object_detection then you can go
>   ahead and generate the TFRecords.

So what I had to do is simply change this line:

```
--data_dir=VOCdevkit
```

to:

```
--data_dir=object_detection/VOCdevkit/
```