# SSD-mobilenet object detection algorithm not converging

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

Hi I am trying to train **SSD -mobilenet** in-order to detect 13 classes. I also trained a **faster rcnn -resnet101** .

My training data images have resolution of 265 * 450 . (most of them) and each class had 400 images.

Then this weird thing happened faster rcnn converged faster  with **batch size of 1** .

But my SSD didn't . It's not converging at all . Here I will put the two graphs ,

Purple - Faster Rcnn | resnet101
Blue   - SSD | mobilenet

[image]

I have seen some have trained this for few classes and obtained good results . If anyone have obtained good results please answer following .

You had only one class , so How fast it converged ? 
What do you think , the network is suffering from vanishing gradents problem or local minima problem ?

Editing - Here I will update the mAp for each category plot .

[image: mAp score for each category when using ssd with mobilenet]

Comment: The loss functions are not necessarily comparable in absolute terms, so from that plot it's not obvious that SSD is not converging.  Can you create eval curves that show mAP over time?

Comment: Well I checked about the activation in some layers , they are saturated .  Any way training loss should reduce to zero as I thought . What make you say it's  not obvious that this is not converging even through training loss remain unchanged  ?

Comment: Training loss in general does not reduce to zero on these objective functions in general, and what they do converge to can be quite different between SSD and Faster R-CNN.  What matters is how well you perform on the test-set in terms of mAP.  Do you have a sense of whether your models perform reasonably?

Comment: Yeah it won't . Since it can be sucked to a local minima. Practically it's impossible . But here I even checked with activation histograms of layers , they are heavily saturated . That made me think this is much of vanishing grad issue . Here I have put the plot please go through them - https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2193

p.s validation mAp also not changing I checked with tensor board.

Comment: So what is the validation mAP? (close to zero?)  And for Faster R-CNN you get high mAP?

Comment: It may help to also post config and label map files.

Comment: No 11 classes I got nearly over 0.7. But for two I didn't get good results .

Comment: Label map file is same . I didn't change. I have this question , if the network is good enough (no gradient or saturation issue )  shouldn't it converge close to zero ? Like faster Rcnn did . In my above link I have posted the activation of a one convolutional layer which is fully  saturated . Isn't that a problem to get such results ?

Comment: Speaking from my experience on COCO and Pascal, it definitely won't converge to zero.  You can easily see that even if you take a fully trained model and run it on the training set, it still makes mistakes.  I wouldn't worry too much about a single saturated activation...

Comment: So when what would be that margin . It's more of validation accuracy as you said tight ?  But if training is stucked at some point there won't be much of validation accuracy also . 

So is it ok to have some saturation activation  and that's normal right . If there's a saturating or a vanishing grad issue , what would you do ?

Comment: training always gets stuck at some point (that's just what it means to converge to something).  The important thing is what your mAP is at that point.  Can you try running eval and posting some of your mAP plots (I'm still quite unclear what they look like)?

Comment: @JonathanHuang I have updated all the evaluation curves in the question . 
(mAp performance by category)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua7bp.png

Comment: This looks like great performance!

Comment: But you see for some-classes  it's really low . Should I add more images ?

Comment: Adding more images will probably help, especially if they contain those low performing classes.

Comment: Here two box prediction layers get almost saturated for even different settings (I changed the learning rate and batch size also -Batch-size was reduced to 8 from 24 ) . Should I touch on relu units , or can it mess things more since this is an already tuned model. ?

Comment: what learning rate did you use ?