# Custom Object Detector using Tensorflow API doesn't detect training data

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, pre-trained-model

I am trying to use `ssd_inception_v2_coco` pre-trained model from [Tensorflow API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) by training it with a single class dataset and also applying Transfer Learning. I trained the net for around `20k steps`(total loss around 1) and using the checkpoint data, I created the inference_graph.pb and used it in the detection code.

To my surprise, when I tested the net with the training data the graph is not able to detect even 1 out of 11 cases (0/11). I am lost in finding the issue.
What might be the possibile mistake?.

P.S : I am not able to run train.py and eval.py at the same time, due to memory issues. So, I don't have info about precision from tensorboard

Has anyone faced similar kind of issue?

Comment: I faced very similar issue: training with SSD lead to a rather high loss (around 5) and running eval didn't produce anything meaningful. Then I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45633957/786559), so I started training with Faster-RCNN, and I have better results. I see proper brounding boxes in tensorboard. 

What do you mean you have 11 cases ?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga I mean to say that for test case of 11 images, I have 0 bounding boxes. Thanks for the link, it helps.