# How long does tensorflow object detection API train.py complete training using CPU only?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am a beginner in machine learning. Recently, I had successfully running a machine learning application using [Tensorflow object detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection).
My dataset is 200 images of object with 300*300 resolution. However, the training had been running for two days and yet to be completed.

I wonder how long would it take to complete a training?? At the moment it is running at global step 9000, how many global step needed to complete the training?

P.S: the training used only CPUs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your desired accuracy and data set of course but I generally stop training when the loss value gets around 4 or less. What is your current loss value after 9000 steps?

Comment: Current loss value alternating between 1 and 2.
So basically does it mean that as long as I have the model checkpoint , I can stop whenever i find the result satisfying enough??
Thank you for your kind response

Comment: Yes, its unlikely your loss will go much lower with more training. You also increase your risk of over-fitting the model to just your training and test data with a lower loss.

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds like your training is not converging.

See the discussion in the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45633957/786559).

Basically, it is recommended that you run `eval.py` in parallel and check how it performs there as well.