# Should I include negative examples for Tensorflow object detection API?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, object-detection

I am building a RCNN detection network using [Tensorflow's object detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection).

My goal is to detect bounding boxes for animals in outdoor videos. Most frames do not have animals and are just of dynamic backgrounds.

Most tutorials focus on training custom labels, but make no mention of negative training samples. How do these class of detectors deal with images which do not contain objects of interest? Does it just output a low probability, or will it force to try to draw a bounding box within an image?

My current plan is to use traditional background subtraction in opencv to generate potential frames and pass them to a trained network. Should I also include a class of 'background' bounding boxes as 'negative data'?

The final option would be to use opencv for background subtraction, RCNN to generate bounding boxes, then a classification model of crops to identify animals versus background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general it's not necessary to explicitly include "negative images".  What happens in these detection models is that they use the parts of the image that don't belong to the annotated objects as negatives.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts (and the great work on the API), just to be clear, what is the expected behavior for a single class detector when confronted with an image without the target object? Low probability score? Bounding box that covers the entire frame?

Comment: The hope in that case is that no boxes would be returned :)

Comment: In my case the addition of negative images was crucial due similarity of my trained object against similar ones that was not annotated. It reduced to zero the number of high confidence FPs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666499/best-strategy-to-reduce-false-positives-googles-new-object-detection-api-on-sa/65798667#65798667

Answer (score 3):

If you expect your model to differentiate between "found a figure" and "no figure", then you will almost certainly need to train it on negative examples.  Label these as "no image".  In the "no image" case, yes, use the entire image as the bounding box; don't suggest that the model recognize anything smaller.

In "no image" cases, you *may* get a smaller bounding box, but that doesn't matter: in inference, you'll simply ignore whatever box is returned for "no image".

Of course, the critical issue here is to try it out, and see how well it works for you.

Comment: Don't see this strategy as being advantageous. As Jonathon mentioned, the background of labeled photos is used as negative examples. If you are just labeling entire photos as a class, this will be an inefficient use of computing power and provide unecessary detection and results. Furthermore, you can simply edit your object detection runner to output images with a detection to one folder, and images without a detection into another folder thus solving the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have found success by scanning my ground truth, copying the box areas plus a margin, then pasting tilings of those box areas onto new background images (guaranteed to have no objects), and creating corresponding XML files with the box category assertions.

I collect non-objects as "uncategorised" boxes - usually from glitches in the output from my latest model. These are tiled (just like the "is-objects") but are not updated in the XML files.

I produce tilings at various scales to build each new training set.

A further explanation and sample python code is here:
https://github.com/brentcroft/ground-truth-productions