# How to remove false detection (False Positives) in Faster RCNN

Tags: performance, tensorflow, object-detection, faster-rcnn

I am using Faster RCNN with Inception V2 on custom dataset. My model is working fine with good detection accuracy. However, I am facing false positive problem when I pass an image to the model I get correct prediction but I am also getting some wrong bounding boxes with high confidence score. Is there any method which can be used as a post-processing to remove these extra detection?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is a common problem with Transfer Learning, you should check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666499/best-strategy-to-reduce-false-positives-googles-new-object-detection-api-on-sa) discussion. In the end it seems that all boils down to what's the source of your false positives.

For instance, once I trained a detector to detect smoke in wildfire images, but it ended up also catching the clouds. To solve that I also annotated the clouds as a new class, and ignored it's detections. This greatly improved the performance.

If it's making wrong detections with high confidence I think it would be hard to solve this problem with only a post-processing.

You could also try hard mining. Altough I'm not really sure how to do it for Faster R-CNN.

Answer (score 0):

While testing the model, a value like this in the code

```
min_score_thresh=0.90
```

If you set this value to 0.90, it will show results that are 90% or more correct.